# Accompanist TestHarness doesn't change the LocalConfiguraiton screenWidthDp when size parameter is provided

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-accompanist

So I am trying to add a UI UnitTest in our app. And tried using the [TestHarness](https://google.github.io/accompanist/testharness/) from Accompanist to test our app in small and large screen device.

I provided the parameter `size` and in their documentation it would modify the `LocalDensity` and didn't mention if it would also modify the `LocalConfiguration`. But our app's use the `screenWidthDp` from `LocalConfiguration` to adjust which composable to display.

Hereis sample code test:

```
@Test
fun smallScreenTest() {
    composeTestRule.setContent {
        TestHarness(size = DpSize(width = 411.dp, height = 800.dp)) {
            MyScreen()
        }
    }

    composeTestRule.onNodeWithTag("BottomNavigation").assertExists()
}

@Test
fun largeScreenTest() {
    composeTestRule.setContent {
        TestHarness(size = DpSize(width = 1280.dp, height = 800.dp)) {
            MyScreen()
        }
    }

    composeTestRule.onNodeWithTag("DrawerNavigation").assertExists()
}
```

If the test `smallScreenTest` is run on tablet emulator it would fail and the `largeScreenTest` will also fail if run on phone emulator.

Anyone use the `TestHarness` and if this is how it works? Do I have to run each tests on different emulators?